# access cache orientdb offline

Tags: java, caching, orientdb, offline

I have a remote orientdb server and according to the documentation 
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Caching.html
It seems possible to access the cache if I'm not online. I search a long time but I can't find how. I'd like to have a `ODataBaseDocumentTx` available offline but if I try

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/test").open("root","root")
```

I have an exception :

> cannot create a connection to remote server address

which is obvious in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need the server online to work with it.
The cache needs the remote server online to work properly.

The code you provide, attempt to connect with the db, it can't works without it:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/test").open("root","root")
```